# Merging table data without keys to join on

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, merge, updates

I have two tables in a MS Sql Server database, imported from different sources, that I want to merge.

#### Table1:

```
Id: int identity primary key  
Name: varchar(50)  
Code: varchar(50)
```

#### Table1 Data:

```
Id, Name, Code
1, 'Knife', '1'  
2, 'Spoon', '1'  
3, 'Fork', '1'  
...
```

#### Table2:

```
Code: varchar(50)
```

#### Table2 Data:

```
Code
'ASF203RNSD2ONF'  
'FD042TOLFB0W30'  
'0FBW2REO90DFRK'  
...
```

I want to update Table1's Code field with the values from Table2's Code field. Both tables have the same number of records and it doesn't matter which code from Table2 goes into which record from Table1, but each record in Table1 has to have a unique code coming from Table2 (each code value in Table2 is unique).

Normally there would be a *Id* in both tables that I could join on, but that isn't the case here, and the Table1 Id isn't sequential (some records have been deleted).

Is the only way to do this is looping thru the records row by agonizing row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added row numbers to the base tables and joined on that. The below code works.

```
update t1
set t1.code = t2.code
from
(select *, row_number() over(order by id) as rNum1  from table1) t1
join 
(select *, row_number() over(order by code) as rNum2 from table2) t2
on t1.rnum1 = t2.rnum2
```

Answer (score 2):

If there are the same number of rows in each table and it doesn't matter which code goes against which record then why not create an arbitrary key field using row number within a sub query and then join on that?

```
SELECT
    TABLE1.ID,
    TABLE1.Name,
    TABLE2.Code

FROM
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS 'Key_Field', ID, Name, Code FROM Table1) TABLE1

    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Code) AS 'Key_Field', Code FROM Table2) TABLE2
    ON
    TABLE1.Key_Field = TABLE2.Key_Field
```

Answer (score 1):

If the number of records is equal, and the order of update is not consequential you can assign an arbitrary row number to each record in both tables, then match on that:

```
WITH T1 AS
(   SELECT  ID, 
            Code,
            RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
    FROM    Table1
), T2 AS
(   SELECT  Code,
            RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
    FROM    Table2
)
UPDATE  T1
SET     Code = T2.Code
FROM    T1
        INNER JOIN T2
            ON T1.RowNumber = T2.RowNumber;
```